# VS C# база данных mssql

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Как можно изменить путь подключения к бд, чтобы при переносе на другой комп заново не прописывать новый путь к базе данных? Чтобы без этого C:\VS2017\Project\Proj2\db.mdf. Видел варианты с |DataDirectory|\db.mdf - не пашет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте варианты: `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath, System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, Application.StartupPath`

Это часть исполняемого пути, куда потом нужно прибавить ваше db.mdf

Answer (score -1):

`System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath`, `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`, `Application.StartupPath`

Из всех вот этих только третий вариант подошел.

```
string dataDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
        string connectionStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="+dataDirectory+@"\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
```

Comment: [интерполяция строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation)